# No value for temp org.json.JSONException: No value for temp

Tags: java, android, json, openweathermap

I have written this function for getting JSON weather data using openweather API. I am having error org.json.JSONException: No value for temp while using OWM_TEMPARATURE But when I don't use temparature field at all I am getting the date and description correctly.

```
private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr, int numDays)
            throws JSONException {


        final String OWM_LIST = "list";
        final String OWM_WEATHER = "weather";
        final String OWM_TEMPERATURE = "temp";
        final String OWM_MAX = "max";
        final String OWM_MIN = "min";
        final String OWM_DESCRIPTION = "main";

        JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
        JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);


        Time dayTime = new Time();
        dayTime.setToNow();


        int julianStartDay = Time.getJulianDay(System.currentTimeMillis(), dayTime.gmtoff);


        dayTime = new Time();

        String[] resultStrs = new String[numDays];
        for(int i = 0; i < weatherArray.length(); i++) {

            String day;
            String description;
            String highAndLow;


            JSONObject dayForecast = weatherArray.getJSONObject(i);


            long dateTime;

            dateTime = dayTime.setJulianDay(julianStartDay+i);
            day = getReadableDateString(dateTime);


            JSONObject weatherObject = dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
            description = weatherObject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);



            JSONObject temperatureObject = dayForecast.getJSONObject(OWM_TEMPERATURE);
            double high = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MAX);
            double low = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MIN);

            highAndLow = formatHighLows(high, low);



            resultStrs[i] = day + " - " + description + " - " + highAndLow;
        }

        for (String s : resultStrs) {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Forecast entry: " + s);
        }
        return resultStrs;

    }
```

**LOGCAT:**

No value for temp

> org.json.JSONException: No value for temp
>                                                                                                 at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
>                                                                                                 at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:609)
>                                                                                                 at
>   com.example.abhishekkumar.sunshine.app.ForecastFragment$FetchWeatherTask.getWeatherDataFromJson(ForecastFragment.java:177)
>                                                                                                 at
>   com.example.abhishekkumar.sunshine.app.ForecastFragment$FetchWeatherTask.doInBackground(ForecastFragment.java:279)
>                                                                                                 at
>   com.example.abhishekkumar.sunshine.app.ForecastFragment$FetchWeatherTask.doInBackground(ForecastFragment.java:92)
>                                                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
>                                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
>                                                                                                 at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>                                                                                                 at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>                                                                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

**And my openweather data is:**

```
{"city":{"id":1260788,"name":"Pālam","coord":{"lon":77.099998,"lat":28.566669},"country":"IN","population":0,"sys":{"population":0}},"cod":"200","message":0.0155,"cnt":7,"list":[{"dt":1467018000,"main":{"temp":38.42,"temp_min":35.56,"temp_max":38.42,"pressure":986.68,"sea_level":1010.85,"grnd_level":986.68,"humidity":62,"temp_kf":2.85},"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03d"}],"clouds":{"all":36},"wind":{"speed":4.17,"deg":107.001},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2016-06-27 09:00:00"},{"dt":1467028800,"main":{"temp":33.82,"temp_min":31.92,"temp_max":33.82,"pressure":985.98,"sea_level":1009.98,"grnd_level":985.98,"humidity":76,"temp_kf":1.9},"weather":[{"id":501,"main":"Rain","description":"moderate rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":{"all":32},"wind":{"speed":3.11,"deg":99.5087},"rain":{"3h":5.54},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2016-06-27 12:00:00"},{"dt":1467039600,"main":{"temp":31.34,"temp_min":30.39,"temp_max":31.34,"pressure":987.55,"sea_level":1011.75,"grnd_level":987.55,"humidity":75,"temp_kf":0.95},"weather":[{"id":501,"main":"Rain","description":"moderate rain","icon":"10n"}],"clouds":{"all":36},"wind":{"speed":2.31,"deg":105.002},"rain":{"3h":4.07},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2016-06-27 15:00:00"},{"dt":1467050400,"main":{"temp":30.15,"temp_min":30.15,"temp_max":30.15,"pressure":988.78,"sea_level":1013.04,"grnd_level":988.78,"humidity":78,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03n"}],"clouds":{"all":32},"wind":{"speed":3.22,"deg":100.501},"rain":{},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2016-06-27 18:00:00"},{"dt":1467061200,"main":{"temp":29.52,"temp_min":29.52,"temp_max":29.52,"pressure":987.7,"sea_level":1012.15,"grnd_level":987.7,"humidity":81,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":64},"wind":{"speed":2.97,"deg":96.0021},"rain":{},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2016-06-27 21:00:00"},{"dt":1467072000,"main":{"temp":26.71,"temp_min":26.71,"temp_max":26.71,"pressure":988.06,"sea_level":1012.31,"grnd_level":988.06,"humidity":94,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":501,"main":"Rain","description":"moderate rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":{"all":76},"wind":{"speed":0.71,"deg":189.5},"rain":{"3h":3.205},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2016-06-28 00:00:00"},{"dt":1467082800,"main":{"temp":29.3,"temp_min":29.3,"temp_max":29.3,"pressure":990,"sea_level":1014.38,"grnd_level":990,"humidity":91,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":{"all":80},"wind":{"speed":2.86,"deg":100.504},"rain":{"3h":0.005},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2016-06-28 03:00:00"}]}
```

Comment: Please put the code in a better format. Provide 4 spaces before each line of code

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same problem.

```
"main":{
        "temp":26.19,
        "temp_min":21.45,
        "temp_max":26.19,
        "pressure":869.02,
        "sea_level":1026.9,
        "grnd_level":869.02,
        "humidity":43,
        "temp_kf":4.75
     }
```

Notice that `temp`, `temp_min`, `temp_max` are inside `main` object in formatted JSON data whereas the code is trying to access `temp_min` and `temp_max` inside `temp` object.

Just make the following changes:

1. Replace `OWM_TEMPERATURE` with `OWM_DESCRIPTION` in `JSONObject temperatureObject = dayForecast.getJSONObject(OWM_TEMPERATURE);`
2. Make `OWM_MAX = "temp_max";`   ( instead of `OWM_MAX = "max"`)
3. Make `OWM_MIN = "temp_min";`   (  instead of `OWM_MIN = "min"`)

And your code will run.

Answer (score 1):

User opt instead of get for JSON parsing. 
e.g. instead of getString(), use optString(). 
Actually when key is not available, will be handled automatically by opt with default value.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON does not have a temp object, but three floats instead,

```
"main" : { "grnd_level" : 1009.13,
        "humidity" : 95,
        "pressure" : 1009.13,
        "sea_level" : 1018.03,
        "temp" : 22.949999999999999,
        "temp_kf" : 0,
        "temp_max" : 22.949999999999999,
        "temp_min" : 22.949999999999999
      },
```

I am guessing these is the value you want to extract.